# Why the "FirstOrDefault()" is not required in the <th> rasor code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build a partial view which can add a record at the top and show the list of added items.

I have the following code. Why it's not necessary to add `FirstOrDefault()` in the `<th>` part of the html table while I had to do it in the "Add" html form? It seems `FirstOrDefault()` is always required since the model is `IEnurable<>`. However, check all the scaffold `Index.cshtml` files, you will find there is no `FirstOrDefault()` in the table head.

Is it a better way to implement one edit page for both adding and deleting actions?

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.MyModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddItem", "MyAction", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Col1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Col1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Col1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Col2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Col2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Col2)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Add" />
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Col1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Col2)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.Col1, item.Col2})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**Update:**

I changed it to `@Html.EditorFor(m => (new Model.MyModel()).Col1)` and this will not carry the value of the first row in the inserting inputs. This should be one of the solution.

Comment: On the line `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Col1)`, put your cursor on `Col1` and press the F12 key. It should show you where `Col1` is defined on your model. Where does it take you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `FirstOrDefault` because your `model` is `IEnumerable`.
So in order to get an instance you have to get one element from the `IEnumerable` thus, `FirstOrDefault`

This presents a problem though, for if the model is null, the page will throw a runtime error when trying to access that `property` `Col1`.

In the `table`, you are iterating over the items in the `model` therefore you won't need to do `FirstOrDefault`

I would recommend creating a model that has a property that is the instance that you're looking to bind to.

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> MyModels { get;set; }
}
```

Then:

```
@model MyNameSpace.MyViewModel

 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyModel.Col1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyModel.Col1)
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, but why the table header (`<th>`) just uses `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Col1)`?

Comment: @NickW - It won't work that way, the `model` is `IEnumerable`, it does not have a property called `Col1`.

Comment: Actually it works, the `<table>...</table>` part is the Visual studio 2012 scaffold-ed code. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @NickW - I don't see how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can Avoid using IEnumerable model in your View.

Model would be something like below.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }


}

public class MyLstModel:MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> lstMyModel { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Models.MyLstModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddItem", "MyAction", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Col1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Col1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Col1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Col2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Col2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Col2)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Add" />
    }

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAdministrator)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.lstMyModel) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.Col1, item.Col2})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Comment: In the view you are still using MyListModel which has the IEnumerable property.  Shouldn't it be @model Models.MyModel ?

Comment: @nik0lias no actually the IEnumerable property is lstMyModel and i've used MyLstModel in view. bad selection of naming